# Posing: only one object moving, incorrectly

Tags: rigging, objects, pose-mode

Apologies if I missed something. Newbie to Blender, none of my searches have helped yet. Perhaps I just don't know the proper terms.
I finished a model, finished (I thought) rigging, and after setting parents with automatic weight only one object moves, and even then not properly.
For instance, it's the knee brace:

[image]

I try to bend the leg, and only the brace comes along for the ride. Even then the bar on the side either remains straight like pictured or just stretches to the underlying face.

[image]

Confusingly, the other side bends properly at the center. They both have separate faces for the top and bottom halves.

Edit: A friend suggested turning on Bone Constraints.
Which fixes the biggest immediate problem. Still need to figure out how to adjust just what follows which bone and how, and... apparently scrape gum off a foot.

[image]

The file: [image]

Comment: perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Nothing so far?
I've been trying everything I can find, no improvement yet.

Comment: First I think that the armature is not well organized, you need to give an IK constraint to the shin, with a controller behind the heel, and also the rigging is bad, and you need to correct this in Weight Paint mode and with the Vertex Groups of the mesh. But perhaps you should follow more tutorials on rigging in Blender, there are a lot.

Comment: Alright, that's a great direction to head. Not many of the tutorials dipped into that yet, and without knowing where the problem lies, I hadn't switched gears yet. Most were 'select mesh, select armature, parent with auto weight.'
Now I know where to point my searches, and can find the tutorials that help there. Thanks.
Heck, wouldn't be opposed to going back a few saves and manually setting up vertex groups if need be.